# PHP image resizing to specific dimensions

Tags: php, html, image

I have a simple form in which you select an image to upload to a folder. Literally only contains `input type="file"`. My aim is to allow users to upload image files and then resize them to a specified height and width, whilst doing this sensibly, so the resize and or crop isn't the corner of a huge image.

That way the user does not have to worry about pre-formatting their image

I saw this function on the PHP documentation pages to resize images

```
/**
* Resize an image and keep the proportions
* @author Allison Beckwith <allison@planetargon.com>
* @param string $filename
* @param integer $max_width
* @param integer $max_height
* @return image
*/
function resizeImage($filename, $max_width, $max_height)
{
    list($orig_width, $orig_height) = getimagesize($filename);

    $width = $orig_width;
    $height = $orig_height;

    # taller
    if ($height > $max_height) {
        $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
        $height = $max_height;
    }

    # wider
    if ($width > $max_width) {
        $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
        $width = $max_width;
    }

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                     $width, $height, $orig_width, $orig_height);

    return $image_p;
}
```

Then I have this script below that moves an uncropped image to a folder

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    $test = is_writable("test");

    echo "The directory 'test' returned $test";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";

    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $name = str_replace('..', '', $name);
    $name = str_replace('/', '', $name);
    $name = str_replace('\\', '', $name);

    // Get file information and set paths
    $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $tempname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $imagePath = "images/";
    $thumbPath = "images/thumbs/";

    // Array of allowed types
    $allowed_file_type = array(
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/jpg",
        "image/gif",
        "image/png"
    );

    if (!in_array($type, $allowed_file_type))
    {
        echo "Type is: $type";

        echo "This file type is not allowed";
    }
    else if($size > 8000000)
    {
        echo "Files can only be up to 8MB";
    }
    else{
        if(!is_dir($imagePath))
        {
            mkdir($imagePath, 0777, true);
        }

        if(!is_dir($thumbPath))
        {
            mkdir($thumbPath, 0777, true);
        }

        /* if(is_dir($imagePath)){
            echo "$imagePath was created on the server";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "$imagePath was not created on the server";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        } */

        if(move_uploaded_file($tempname, $imagePath.$name))
        {
            echo "Stored in: $imagePath$name";
            $crop = resizeImage($name, 370, 370);

            echo imagepng($crop);


        } 
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong";
        }
    }

    }
```

Once the image has been moved could I use the crop function to crop the image I just uploaded, and then move that image to another folder?

`$crop = resizeImage($name, 370, 370);`

```
if(move_uploaded_file($crop, $thumbPath.$name))
        {


        } 
        else{

        }
```

Essesentially I have an `/images` folder and inside this I have a `/thumbs` folder, just in case the user ever wants the original back for whatever reason.

I can provide more detailed code if necessary.

I may be barking up the wrong tree, so if there is a simpler or more straight-forward approach I'd be interested. I will obviously improve my question, given the most appropriate answer, so that it helps others.

Comment: You should use imagecrop if you want to crop an image, not this script.

Comment: Sorry, that was poor wording. I want to resize to 370 by 370 but sometimes users upload images that are wider than they are tall, or taller than they are wide. At the moment I'm having to manually trim these down.

Comment: This will help you http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php